# Can we create Desktop application in php

Tags: php, desktop-application

My concern is to know, That can we create desktop application in PHP Like:- other applications on our desktop. If yes then give some references or ideas, How to create desktop applications

Comment: [Yes & No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP-GTK).

Comment: wxPHP is one such solution to this, but the binaries are not usually available for PHP distributions, so you'd need to compile it yourself if you wish to distribute your software. Also, I found that although the lead maintainer is doing a valiant job, he no longer has time to maintain the project, and there are still some stability issues to fix before I would consider using it seriously.

Comment: For sure you can. Follow this tutorial for the easiest way -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jesZur7Ym6w

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes some how you can.

PHP Desktop is an open source project founded by Czarek Tomczak in 2012 to provide a way for developing native desktop GUI applications using web technologies such as PHP, HTML5, JavaScript and SQLite. [Follow here](http://phpocean.com/tutorials/back-end/create-your-first-desktop-application-with-php-and-php-desktop/4)

Some of the tutorials are here. 
[Here is youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9U1cOB58b8) 
[Here is another useful tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/3-ways-develop-cross-platform-desktop-apps-php/)

Comment: Its create exe file that allow users to install it in their desktops?

Comment: @RahulRaghav welcome. Please accept this answer as correct. Click on the tick mark, if you think this helps you. Also upvote it to make it more useful for other people

Comment: Hello, I have checked these tutorial. It's only provide Windows. Can I get Mac software also?
Actually I need mac software.

Answer (score 1):

You can make desktop apps with php using tools such as Nightrain, WXPHP or TideSDK
https://www.sitepoint.com/3-ways-develop-cross-platform-desktop-apps-php/